# Find the size of the rows by date

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've done some research on figuring out a table size variations for the past few days.
I wonder is it even possible to find the size of the rows in a table by date? For instance, between `2020-01-01` and `2020-01-31`.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      column_name    |     data_type    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         | int(10) unsigned |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       created_at    |       date       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      some column    |    varchar(255)  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I don't think it's possible for me to append a date condition inside the query below.

```sql
SELECT
  table_name "Table Name",
  table_rows "Rows Count",
  round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) "Table Size (MB)"
FROM
  information_schema.TABLES
WHERE
  table_schema = "DB NAME"
  AND table_name = "TABLE NAME";
```

Comment: The values in the information schema are the current values, e.g., as you expected, they do not contain historical data. If you need that, you may need to run a query that stores this result once a day or so. More importantly, they are (sometimes very inaccurate) estimates, so those daily values might not even differ. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Does your table maybe have a "created at"-column, so you may be able to estimate new rows per day? Could you run a daily job (with more accurate queries, e.g. getting actual row count, maybe length of varchar columns, ...)?

Comment: @Solarflare The first question of yours is exactly what I was looking for. I'm curious whether I could find the size by running just the query itself or not.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB doesn't keep a history about table and index sizes. As far as I know there is also no operating system that logs file sizes. This is usually the job of a monitoring tool.

If your binary log is enabled (`log-bin=1`) you should be able to get DML statements together with a timestamp for a specific table. Binary log can be displayed by `mysqldump` tool, or by using the RPL API of MariaDB Connector/C. Here is an example output of mysqldump

```
#200227 17:34:24 server id 1  end_log_pos 759 CRC32 0x7934578c  Query   thread_id=11    exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1582821264/*!*/;
insert into t1 (a,b) values (1, "foo")
/*!*/;
```

In case you use the more readable SQL syntax which also specifies the column names, you could add an additional column `c` with datatype timestamp and replay the log. Then c would contain the timestamp from binary log (=1582821264) and not the actual date.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Georg. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As Georg said, MySQL and MariaDB dont keep a table stats history, however you can build the system yourself.

### Create a table storing all tables' stats history

It will keep for each day, all sizes/rows information available in the information_schema, for all tables.

```
CREATE TABLE TB_STATS_HISTORY ( 
    DT DATE ,
    TB_SCHEMA VARCHAR(64),
    TB_NAME VARCHAR(64),
    TB_ROWS INT,
    TB_DATA_LENGTH INT,
    TB_INDEX_LENGTH INT,
    TB_AI INT,
    TB_SIZEKB INT
);

ALTER TABLE `TB_STATS_HISTORY` ADD PRIMARY KEY( `DT`, `TB_SCHEMA`, `TB_NAME`);
```

### Create a procedure that will gather stats on demand

You will call the procedure passing it the schema where the tables are (just your  DB name probably) and a date.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Gather_Table_Stats` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Gather_Table_Stats`(arg_schema VARCHAR(64), arg_date DATE) 

BEGIN

DECLARE val_schema  VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE val_table   VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE val_rows    INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE val_data    INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE val_idx     INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE val_ai      INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE val_size    INT DEFAULT NULL;

DECLARE done        TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;

DECLARE cursor1 
 CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME,
    TABLE_ROWS,
    DATA_LENGTH,
    INDEX_LENGTH,
    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 )) `SizeKB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema = arg_schema AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cursor1;

my_loop:
LOOP

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 
    INTO val_schema, val_table, val_rows, val_data, val_idx, val_ai, val_size ;
  
  IF done THEN 
    LEAVE my_loop; 
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO MTG.TB_STATS_HISTORY (DT, TB_SCHEMA, TB_NAME, TB_ROWS, TB_DATA_LENGTH , TB_INDEX_LENGTH, TB_AI, TB_SIZEKB)
    VALUES (arg_date, val_schema, val_table, val_rows, val_data, val_idx, val_ai, val_size);

  END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cursor1;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

### Activate the scheduler

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

You can see if the scheduler is running by checking the processes

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

Should output one process with *User: event_scheduler*

### Add an event that will call the procedure once a day

Here I create an event that first starts today at noon, and repeat every day at noon indefinitely

```
CREATE EVENT event_daily_stats
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2020-09-08 12:00:00'
DO
    CALL Gather_Table_Stats('your_schema',CURRENT_DATE);
```

### You are done

Everyday at noon, the stats information of all your tables will be saved in your history table

```
DT        |TB_SCHEMA  |TB_NAME  |TB_ROWS|TB_DATA_LENGTH |TB_INDEX_LENGTH|TB_AI  |TB_SIZEKB  
2020-09-08|your_schema|Table_1  |3287   |131072         |0              |NULL   |128
2020-09-08|your_schema|Table_2  |166    |29124          |4096           |251    |32
2020-09-08|your_schema|Table_3  |0      |16384          |98304          |1      |112
```